# Find elements where class = a certain class and delete class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of divs with no class when they are clicked they get the class of 'active' however when i click the second div in the list i want any other div that is using the class of active to drop the class of active.

The HTML:-

```
    <div id="div1" onclick="classchanger(this); return false;"><p>first item</p></div>

    <div id="div2" onclick="classchanger(this); return false;"><p>second item</p></div>

    <div id="div3" onclick="classchanger(this); return false;"><p>third item</p></div>
```

The Jquery to add the class when a div is clicked:-

```
    function classchanger(e) {
    $(e).addClass( "active" );  

    };
```

However i need to remove this class should a different div be clicked on such as:- (An example of the code i'm trying to achieve.)

```
    function classchanger(e) {
    if(any div == class of active){ 
    the divs with a class of active .removeClass( "active" )
    }
    $(e).addClass( "active" );  
    };
```

Any idea on this or alternative methods i would be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just change your `classchanger` function to

```
function classchanger(e) {
    $("#container").find(".active").removeClass("active"); 
    $(e).addClass( "active" );  
};
```

The selector selects all the elements with the class "active", and removes the class from them. Then you just add the class to the element you were clicking on.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works great and so obviously simple i can't believe i never thought of it. This has saved me having to wake up in the middle of the night with that line of code in my head. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome. Please remember to mark the answer as correct when you can.

Comment: How do i go about doing this to just the selected divs if i were to put it in a container. How could i just narrow it down to say any divs within this container? I have found i have other items on the page that also use the class of active so i could do with narrowing it down.

Comment: `$(e).closest(".classOfContainerHere").find(".active").removeClass("active")`

Comment: Edited my answer to include code for finding only `.active` elements in the `#container`.

Answer (score -2):

HTML

```
   <div id="div1" class="item"><p>first item</p></div>
    <div id="div2" class="item"><p>second item</p></div>
    <div id="div3" class="item"><p>third item</p></div>
```

JS (jquery )

```
$(".item").on("click",function() {
  $(".item").each(function() { $(this).removeClass("active"); });
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I imagine your suggestion will work, but you don't need the `.each()`, you can just say `$(".item").removeClass("active")` to remove the class from all matching elements.

Comment: force of habbit, ( there may be another process required on the items to remove class )- no reason for a down vote, as this solution also removes inline click event and works within the dom scope of the 'item' elements

Comment: I didn't downvote. Like I said, I imagine it will work, it's just not as simple or efficient as it could be.

Comment: Thank you nnnnnn, Loyalar an rob this has solved my problems.

Comment: sorry, - not sure why the downvote , i'ts a widely used unobtrusive method - hey ho SO, Great Stuff, Gnat, as long as you got sorted.